# Can my ISP know that I have more than one Google Drive account?

Tags: privacy, google, monitoring, confidentiality, isp

So, I have 2 Google Drive accounts. Let's say Drive A and Drive B.

If one day I login/upload to Drive A then log out, then login/upload to Drive B, can they notice that I have 2 different accounts? Or can they only know that I accessed Google Drive without knowing anything more?

And what if I login/upload to both accounts at the very same time? Do they know then?

Comment: If you tunnel your connections through a VPN you will be sure to avoid the introspection of an ISP. You should learn how to use Wireshark so that you can see what your ISP 'sees'. This is more a question of privacy than security, so I expect the moderators will tell you that in due course.

Comment: @EdDaniel Follow-up question: "Can my VPN provider see if I have two Google Drive accounts?'

Comment: OP, are the hostnames of the two Google drives the same?

Comment: Why would the ISP care? Do you have some limits that apply to Google Drive instances?

Comment: @Marcel A lot of fear from ISPs stems from VPN marketing departments, acting like ISPs will constantly monitor everything you do in real time for some bizarre reason.

Comment: @EdDaniel yes I know about VPN, but I just want to know if they can know about my double account without VPN

Comment: @mti2935 sorry but I dont know what hostname means?

Comment: @Marcel they dont care, just want to know. Pure personal 'technical' curiousity

Comment: @anyanya   Sorry for not being clearer.  Does the URL for both Google drives start with `https://drive.google.com/`?

Comment: @mti2935 yes of course

Comment: @mti2935 let me confirm.. so my ISP only know that I login/upload traffic to google drive, then know I relog and make upload traffic again without knowing that I have dual account, right?

Comment: Again, why do you believe your ISP will care if you have two accounts? What is the threat model here?

Comment: @MechMK1 Threat model? Nothing. Just curious about it.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fast response is "no", your ISP can not see how many accounts of gdrive you have and which of them you are using. In fact, as far as I know, the majority of the traffic to google services is TLS(probably all), so the only thing that your ISP can see is that you are accessing to google services by analyzing the TLS client hello SNI or by checking your DNS resolutions.